# Deploy from VSTS to Azure Web App outside of my domain

Tags: .net, azure, deployment, azure-devops

Unfortunately I am unable to add my Team Services Account to the Azure account that I want to publish to, this means I have to find another way.

I have FTP working but it takes a very long time so the app is down for an extended period and it's using lots of build minutes.

Can anyone suggest a faster approach to publishing to an Azure Web App that doesnt require integration with the Team Services Account please?

Answer (score 2):

The accounts don't have to be linked. You can add an [Azure service endpoint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vs/alm/release/getting-started/deploy-to-azure#createazurecon) and then use it normally within any of the Azure deployment tasks.

Comment: I will try that again, but the first time I did it it didn't come back with any of the web apps in my subscription.. I think that you need to add the account in Azure for that to work... i'll try again now.

Comment: I am unable to access the 'old portal' for the Azure subscription which means I can't create a Management Certificate for it. Credentials based authentication is not working. Thus I am stuck!

Comment: you should be able to use Azure PowerShell to get a certificate via `Get-AzurePublishSettingsFile`, which will contain a "classic" portal management certificate.

Comment: @JamieGilbert When you select "Certificate Based" authentication type, there should be a blue "publish settings file" link on that dialog which allow you to download the "ManagementCertificate" directly. Did you try that?